# Array of String printing Optional, why?

Tags: swift

I am playing with Arrays in playground and I am bit confused. Here is code:

```
var players = ["tob", "cindy", "mindy"] //["tob", "cindy", "mindy"]
print(players.isEmpty) // False
var currentPlayer = players.first // "tob"
print(currentPlayer) // "Optional("tob")\n"
```

Why does it says "Optional"?
I found explanation: "The property *first* actually returns an optional, because if the array were empty, *first* would return nil."

But it is not empty. .isEmpty //false, So I am not understanding this.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to think of `Optional` is that this may or may not have a value. What is the first element of an empty list? There is no such thing. It is not a value. We call that lack of a value `nil` or `.None`.

In Swift a variable must have a specific type. So your example:

```
let currentPlayer = players.first
```

What is the type of `currentPlayer`? It may be a `String`, or it may be nothing at all. It is a "maybe string" and in Swift that's called an `Optional<String>`. Whether `players` has elements or doesn't have elements doesn't change the type of `currentPlayer`.

If you want to do something if-and-only-if the variable has a value, then there are many ways. The simplest is `if-let`.

```
let players = ["tob", "cindy", "mindy"] //["tob", "cindy", "mindy"]
print(players.isEmpty) // False
if let currentPlayer = players.first {
    print(currentPlayer)
}
```

This will print `tob` as you're expecting.

Another very common approach is the `guard let`

```
let players = ["tob", "cindy", "mindy"] //["tob", "cindy", "mindy"]
guard let currentPlayer = players.first else { return }
print(currentPlayer)
```

This lets you avoid nesting the rest of your function inside of curly braces, but otherwise is the same approach.

It is possible to convert an Optional into its underlying type using `!`, but this is very dangerous and should be avoided except where absolutely necessary. Tools like `if-let` and `guard-let` (and also `Optional.map`) are almost always preferred.

But the key here is to understand that all Swift variables have a single type, and sometimes that type is "maybe it has a value, maybe it doesn't."

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate what you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the description of `first`, we will see that it always returns `optional` type:

```
public var first: Self.Generator.Element? { get }
```